# Is explicitly clearing/zeroing sensitive variables after use sensible?

Tags: c, linux, security, memory-management

I have noticed some programs explicitly zero sensitive memory allocations after use. For example, OpenSSL has a method to clear the memory occupied by an RSA key:

"Frees the RSA structure rsa. This function should always be used to free the RSA structure as it also frees sub-fields safely by clearing memory first."

http://www.rsa.com/products/bsafe/documentation/sslc251html/group__COMMON__RSA__KEY__FUNCS.html#aRSA_free

Where any (C/C++) program contains sensitive variables like this, should you explicitly zero the memory, as above? (Or, is zero'ing memory an act of paranoia or just a safeguard)?

Also, when a program finishes, any allocated memory is eventually allocated to another program. On a Linux system, is the memory cleaned or sanitised before being allocated to another program? Or, can the second program read some of the old memory contents of the first program?

Comment: I'm not sure that that quote is claiming that it's zeroing memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On a Linux system, is the memory cleaned or sanitised before being allocated to another program?

Yes, on any respectable desktop OS, memory is sanitised when passed from a process to another. The cleaning step that you have observed is to protect from other attacks, from code executing in the same address space or obtaining privileges allowing it to read memory from the target process's memory space.

> Where any (C/C++) program contains sensitive variables like this, should you explicitly zero the memory, as above?

It's a very sensible safeguard to erase this sensitive data as soon as you don't need it any more.

Comment: @Ben Voigt It is included in the desktop OSes for the purpose of this answer. I am not saying that it is used only there. But now that I have read your answer, I see your point.

Comment: Cryptography isn't just desktops either :)

Answer (score 1):

When programs/libraries like GPG and OpenSSL with sensitive cryptographic data explicitly zero memory, it has nothing to do with a fear that the memory will be "reassigned" to other programs which could read the data. This is fundamentally impossible due to the way multiprocess/multiuser operating systems work.

The reasons for zeroing data are twofold:

1. If the code is a library, you want to protect against careless information leakage by the calling program. Even though the memory that contained sensitive information cannot be reassigned to another process, freed memory can and will be reused *in the same process* as long as it's still running the same program image (i.e. as long as it hasn't called `exec*`). A buggy program might call `malloc` then write the buffer to disk without first filling the whole allocated object, in which case, old potentially-sensitive information could be leaked to disk. Issues of this kind exist in major real-world products like Microsoft Office (though they may have been fixed by now).
2. Even if the code is not a library but a stand-alone program, you may want to zero sensitive data in memory before freeing it for paranoia purposes. If the feds bust down your door and haul away your computer, they can subsequently examine whatever happened to be on the swap partitions. If they're careful in removing it they might even be able to examine ram contents. If you're paranoid about physical attacks, you want to ensure that passphrases, etc. *do not exist* anywhere in ram or on disk after they're used. Many cryptographic programs even want to have root access so they can `mlockall` their memory to prevent anything from getting swapped to disk (though in my view this is stupid - trading a serious risk of root compromise due to bugs in the software for paranoia about physical attack).

If you are not worried about physical attacks, or if you're sufficiently in touch with reality to realize that physical attackers probably have better ways of getting your passphrase than swap partition forensics, then reason #2 is probably mostly bogus, but most software addresses it anyway just to keep the nutcases happy. :-)

Comment: Nothing about multiprocess OSes prevent reassigning a memory block to a different process, as memory requirements dictate.  Most OSes will sanitize the memory when doing so, but on Linux this step is explicitly optional.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you meant (as per your answer) at the application level (with administrative configuration) rather than at the administration level.

Comment: It's a kernel option to make it so it's even possible, but then the application has to explicitly request the behavior to when calling `mmap` (since normally `mmap` of anonymous pages must give zero-filles pages).

Comment: @R: Right, but you have to assume that anyone trying to sift through memory is going to pass the option.

Comment: Or you could just not enable the dangerous kernel option. Even if you explicitly zero buffers, there's *plenty* of additional information leakage that could potentially be dangerous which you cannot control - stack frames, data allocated by the standard C library or third-party libraries, etc. I wouldn't hesitate to say any system with `CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED` enabled is almost certainly vulnerable.

Comment: @R: I absolutely agree.  But you have to know about an option before you can make sure it's correctly set.

Comment: Yes but that's an administrator's responsibility not a programmer's. Surely Linus could add `CONFIG_IGNORE_UID_GID_CAPS_AND_TREAT_EVERYONE_AS_ROOT` option for fools to enable, and it would not be application authors' responsibility to be aware of it or code to work around the massive vulnerability it creates. :-)

Comment: @R: True, but an application programmer might reasonably want to check that the option is correctly set and display a nasty warning if not.

Answer (score 1):

From a security standpoint, your memory might contain data that you would not like to linger around. If the process crashes and the core file will have the complete dump of the memory. It is possible to dig into those core files and mine data. For a support call, if you have to send that core file, you would feel safer if the memory is sanitized after use. When I worked on VMS, some sensitive customers would refrain from even giving us the dump files (making this extremely difficult to debug).

Comment: Giving your core files to a third party is a very bad idea even if you zero freed memory. You're still likely to have a lot of privileged information (perhaps something as simple as customer names) in memory that's still in use. And since it's the application vendor you're having to trust anyway, why would you trust them if they say they zeroed memory when you obviously can't trust them to write software that's sufficiently correct not to crash??

Answer (score 0):

> On a Linux system, is the memory cleaned or sanitised before being allocated to another program?

It depends, the details are found in the `mmap` man page:

> MAP_UNINITIALIZED (since Linux 2.6.33)
>
> ```
>           Don't clear anonymous pages.  This flag is intended to improve
>           performance on embedded devices.  This flag is only honored if the
>           kernel was configured with the CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED option.
>           Because of the security implications, that option is normally enabled
>           only on embedded devices (i.e., devices where one has complete control
>           of the contents of user memory).
> ```

---

Zeroing the memory before returning it to the OS is iffy at best, what happens if your process was killed by a signal before it had a chance to do so?  Configure the kernel to perform the sanitization for you.

Comment: Note that this option also would preclude COW zero page semantics for new anonymous pages, which could improve performance a lot in some instances, but could also lead to a lot more swapping, including swapping of worthless uninitialized data to disk...