# Erasing sensitive information from memory

Tags: c, security, memset

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089332/is-explicitly-clearing-zeroing-sensitive-variables-after-use-sensible) I'm curious how one would do this in C. When receiving the information from another program, we probably have to assume that the memory is writable.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538366/can-memset-function-call-be-removed-by-compiler) stating that a regular memset maybe optimized out and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266820/in-clang-how-do-you-use-per-function-optimization-attributes#comment41210667_26266820) stating that memsets are the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I'd suggest using volatile pointers with `memset()`. Those will not be optimized away.

Comment: Having read your links, how do you know that you *can* get rid of data that has come to your program through the OS, perhaps through more than one buffer? The only way you could be sure of that would be to clean up the hard drive at every shutdown. Apart from that you could encrypt all sensitive data until the point of use and then re-use any memory for specific but meaningless tasks that the compiler will not optimise out, for example to read in a "lorem ipsum" text file and do something that the compiler cannot deduce is meaningless.

Comment: @Igor S.K That was also one of the things that crossed my mind, but in the end it leads to preventing the memset from beeing optimized out. I dont know if I put to much weight into the comment of R.. linked above, but it feels like his remark would still apply.

Comment: @Weather Vane  You are probably right, but I would like to stick to the scenario where there is one copy of the data in memory and we have a writable pointer to it. Whatever happens while swapping  is not of my concern right now. In memory encryption feels wrong because in the end it's only obfuscation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you have provided is not quite valid: the compiler can optimize out a variable setting operation when it can detect that there are no side effects and the value is no longer used.

So, if your code uses some shared buffer, accessible from multiple locations, the `memset` would work fine. Almost.

Different processors use different caching policies, so you might have to use memory barriers to ensure the data (zero's) have reached memory chip from the cache.

So, if you are not worried about hardware level details, making sure compiler can't optimize out operation is sufficient. For example, memsetting block before releasing it would be executed.

If you want to ensure the data is removed from all hardware items, you need to check how the data caching is implemented on your platform and use appropriate code to force cache flush, which can be non-trivial on multi-core machine.

Comment: Well I'm not really worried of anyone accessing the cache of my CPU.  Just to make sure I got you right: Your suggestion boils down to declaring the pointer volatile, memseting and freeing, right?

Comment: @funkysash These two are alternatives. `volatile` disables a lot of optimizations due to language requirements. Clearing before freeing simply tells the compiler the pointer is passed somewhere (as it doesn't actually know what `free` does), so any of the data modification can't be optimized out.