# C++: Overwrite std::string in Cache

Tags: c++, string

I got a string variable (contains passphrase) and would [like to overwrite it's value with a sequence of '0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089332/is-explicitly-clearing-zeroing-sensitive-variables-after-use-sensible) before the variable is released. I tought about doing something like:

```
void overwrite(std::string &toOverwrite){
    if(toOverwrite.empty())
        return;
    else{
        std::string removeString;
        size_t length = toOverwrite.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            removeString += "0";
        }
       toOverwrite = removeString;
    }    
}
```

But somehow this doesn't feel right.

1. First because it seems to produce much overhead in the for loop.
2. Moreover I'm not sure if the last line would really overwrite the string. I know that e.g. in Java strings are immutable and therefore can not be overwritten at all. They are not immutable in C++ (at least not std::string) but would `toOverwrite = removeString` really replace `toOverwrite` or just make that the "pointer" of `toOverwrite` will point to `removeString`?
3. Is it possible that my compiler will [optimize the code and removes this overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483713/erasing-sensitive-information-from-memory)?

Maybe I should use the `std::string::replace` method or change the datatype to char* / byte[]?

Comment: As far as the loop overhead goes, you could just initialize your string with `std::string removeString(toOverwrite.size(), '0');` – but that won't resolve your 2nd and 3rd questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that will just swap and free pointers, leaving the passphrase somewhere in memory which is no longer pointed to. If you want to overwrite the string data, do:

```
std::fill(toOverwrite.begin(), toOverwrite.end(), '0');
```

And you don't need a test for an empty string either.

Comment: It's still possible the compiler will optimize this out, if the string isn't used anymore.

Comment: I suppose the only way to _really_ guarantee that the string will be overwritten is to add some inline assembly code?

Comment: Could volatile be helpfull?

Comment: @BoPersson The compiler can't know it won't be used if its a reference parameter of a function - anyone could call it.

Comment: @Galik The compiler can choose to make overwrite() inline, in which case it can easily see that the value in the string is not used anymore.

Comment: @mindriot I believe assembly could be optimised too. The only way sure way is to use OS API, i.e. `SecureZeroMemory` on Windows

Comment: if that's an out of line function in its own TU, the compiler and linker would have to work almost insanely hard to optimise it away.

Comment: @Tom - The major compilers *do* that now. With "Whole program optimization" or "Link-time code generation" (whatever they call it), g++, clang, and VC++ will inline functions across TUs.

Comment: Dynamic library it is then... (looks furtively over shoulder in case of yet more unexpected optimization possibilities).