# Is it a security vulnerability to be able to read from a malloc'ed range that has not been assigned a value?

Tags: c, malloc

Suppose you have the following code:

```
int *i = malloc(sizeof (int));
printf("%i", *i);
```

Does `i` potentially get access to a memory space which may have contained sensitive data earlier and not yet erased?

Of course I realise that this may not be a matter of concern on most modern machines, but I was curious if it is a real concern in smaller low-powered systems such as embedded platforms, which often have very low memory sizes.

Comment: The C language makes no guarantees of any kind what might be in uninitialized memory, but most implementations will add security features. BTW, `printf` requires a string.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which defines enough context to allow the code to make sense. Currently it does not and requires much additional clarity and detail.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the example. It should be fixed now.

Comment: *which may have contained sensitive data earlier and not yet erased?* If your code left that value in memory, **it left that value in memory**.   And it can be read by **anything** that can access the address space of the process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is explicitly clearing/zeroing sensitive variables after use sensible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089332/is-explicitly-clearing-zeroing-sensitive-variables-after-use-sensible)

Comment: Strictly speaking, I would say 'no, it is not a security vulnerability'. That being said, it may expose a security vulnerability in the underlying designs, architectures, implementations, assumptions ....

Comment: @stark i would say yes

Answer (score 1):

The question in your title can be answered, though the shown code is hopefully not compilable.

The answer is yes.

If you allow freshly allocated non-initialised memory to be read and the content being leaked (i.e. somehow reaches the outside) then you risk that security relevant values from former uses of that area get known. This is because the point of dynamic memory allocation is to reuse freed memory for other purposes.

A protective memory management, based on a sufficiently effective separation of accessable memory spaces between processes (I assume this to require hardware supported memory management) can ensure that no process gets to read anything from the memory space of a different process.
Based on that, a process design can make sure that any outputting process does not have access to memory which might contain security information. That however requires careful design and the discipline to obey that design.
In the situation that there are by accident or for lack of design, security-accessing processes which do also output, both in dynamically allocated memory AND do some mistakes as implied by your question, the separation of memory (address spaces) does not protect.

Admittedly I assume that your question implies this situation, with design details AND mistakes being made. Then the answer is yes (as simplified above).

Comment: I'd say the answer is no.  Whether or not a value can be read from memory not cleared after a call to `malloc()` is irrelevant as to whether or not the value has been stored securely. If that value is in the address space of a process the ability to read or not read it via a `malloc()`'d pointer is irrelevant - it's **there** and available to anything that can read the process's memory.  And if it's not in the memory of the process, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Fair enough, make an answer and elaborate on the memory management details and process protection you are assuming. I will do the same.

Comment: As a general rule, the memory management system, presumably the kernel of the OS on which the program/process is being run is always able to read the contents of the memory right? So when a process terminates, freeing up the memory, I was under the impression that most common kernels don't zero it by default. So that memory could be assigned to any other process that requests dynamic memory allocation. I did use malloc in my example of course, but I believe the general characteristic is the same across all programming languages with low-level memory access.

Answer (score 1):

C does not define "security vulnerability" so a spec'd answer per C is unavailable.

Per common security concerns, it is a security vulnerability.

Yet attempting to read an uninitialized `int` is *indeterminate* - even a trap may result.  To avoid this, read as `unsigned char`.

```
unsigned char *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
printf("%x\n", *p);
```